# I can only hear my xbox 360 audio not see the picture

Tags: xbox-360

Whenever I turn my Xbox 360 on I can hear everything, but I can't see anything. I've tried adjusting the AV cables and I've tried everything everyone says, but it still doesn't work. Is it completely broken?

Comment: Are the connections dirty? Try cleaning the AV cables with isopropyl (rubbing alcohol) on a cotton swab, and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Xbox using a plug & play while holding "Left trigger + Y" This resets your display settings.
Also check the hdmi switch on the display cable, set it to tv not hdmi.